# How can I read data from powerpoint

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powerpoint, readfile

I have to work with data in MS powerpoint file, but I don't know how to open and process data in powerpoint file. Please help me!

My programming language is C# and use visual studio 2010.

Answer (score 4):

You need the [Microsoft interop assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57%28VS.80%29.aspx). You can then access the powerpoint files, but keep in mind you have to have powerpoint installed for it to work since it uses your powerpoint instance to access the file (Excel and Word use the same technique when accessing those types of files).

Here's another helpful link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aax7sdch%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308825) is a good KB on controlling PowerPoint files from C#